# Combining two different timestamp dataframes through linear interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master and slave dataframes. I want to append slave data to master dataframe using interpolation. Because, both have different timestamps. Example,

```
mas_df = 

     index               M24
2019-01-31 15:11:47   299.899098
2019-01-31 15:51:17   338.969140


sla_df = 
index                     POA
2019-01-31 15:10:00     99.78411
2019-01-31 15:11:00     97.64976
2019-01-31 15:12:00    103.60300
2019-01-31 15:50:00    102.94610
2019-01-31 15:51:00    108.54370
2019-01-31 15:52:00    113.74820
2019-01-31 15:53:00    121.27410
```

Appending the column of slav_df to mas_df is the objective.

My expected output is:

```
mas_df = 
     index               M24           M24_POA 
2019-01-31 15:11:47   299.899098       102.31  # np.interp(15+(11/60)+(47/3600), [15+11/60,15+(12/60)],[97.64976,103.60300])
2019-01-31 15:51:17   338.969140       110.01  # np.interp(15+(51/60)+(17/3600), [15+51/60,15+(52/60)],[108.54370,113.74820])
```

My present code takes the nearest value

```
aux_df=sla_df['POA'].reindex(mas_df.index,method='nearest').add_prefix(mas_df.columns[0])  
 mas_df = aux_df
```

My present output

```
mas_df = 
     index               M24           M24_POA 
2019-01-31 15:11:47   299.899098       103.60300  
2019-01-31 15:51:17   338.969140       113.74820
```

How do I make changes to my present code to include the interpolated values?

Comment: Please add an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Comment: @ralex I minimized the length of question

Comment: the original example was fine but you haven't put your inputs into the form of an MVCE so that I can cut and paste it into an interpreter and help you.

Comment: @ralex Thanks for new thing MVCE. I have no idea about it. The interpreter part sounds interesting to me. Can you give an example question MVCE so I can readily change it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by interpolating in the slave dataframe and then adding those values to master as a new column:

```
for i in mas_df.index.values:
    sla_df.loc[i] = np.nan
sla_df = sla_df.sort_index().interpolate(method='time')
mas_df['M24_POA'] = [sla_df.loc[i]['POA'] for i in mas_df.index.values]
```

This results in:

```
mas_df =

      index            M24        M24_POA
2019-01-31 15:11:47 299.899098  102.313131
2019-01-31 15:51:17 338.969140  110.018308
```

Comment: `for` loop took longer time and I force stopped it. Instead, I concated  `nandf = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=mas_df.index, columns=slv_df.columns)'  to the slv_df`. Then, interpolated. This worked pretty quick just like that. Thanks